# How can I share my Evdo dongle's Internet through a TP-Link WiFi router?

Tags: connection-sharing

I have a BSNL Evdo Dongle (Teracom T-U500) which I am using on a PC.

Recently I bought a [TP-Link MR3020 WiFi router](http://www.tp-link.in/products/details/TL-MR3020.html) to use with my Evdo modem, but came to know that it is unsupported by the WiFi router.

This router has an RJ45 port, so I want to share my Evdo dongle's Internet connection that I am using in my PC through the TP-Link MR3020 WiFi router to use with my smartphone.

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Comment: Hey, wondering if answer worked out for you ?

Answer (score 0):

attach the EVDO device directly to the router, go to the router page, check how it is connected. If it shows HSPA change it to something that says, CDMA or CDMA2000, make sure you've entered login details of your EVDO connection also tbe dialling number has to be correct for bsnl it is #777. Once you save those detalls in your router, allow it to reboot and wait for 2-3 minutes for it to dial and establish an EVDO connection.